# should I bind this to the return value of jQuery on() or the handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind

I have found two ways of using Javascript's native `bind` as I migrate away from jQuery.proxy():

```
this.thing.on(event, someHandler.bind(this))
```

and

```
this.thing.on(event, someHandler).bind(this)
```

As far as I can tell, they both do the same thing, but I'm worried that the latter might cause issues in the `on()` (or any function in its place). The former syntax is what I'm used to from `$.proxy()`, and to me looks like it's explicitly binding to the handler, so I'm leaning towards using that syntax.

Are these two lines actually doing the same exact thing? And if not, which is the safer option?

Comment: did you try the second one? did that wok? they are not doing the same thing for sure

Comment: yes as I stated they both do the same thing in my case

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mr1zw9z0/1/ - I don't think so, they are not even close

Comment: In your second example you are binding to whatever `.on` returns. Depending on what `thing` is these 2 might be equivalent but this is **highly** unlikely. And if it is `jQuery` object then it is simply false. I assume that first snippet is what you want unless you are dealing with some very weird issue.

Comment: [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is very different from [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)!

Comment: the bind you are using, it's just the means of changing the context on the first example, you are assigning `this` to the `handler` as the context, whereas in the second example, the context is assigned on the `on` method probably incorrectly.  to bind the way jquery does it's a little different you assign the event to a parent and then you look if the target is the same as the one you wish to target.

Comment: [The correct bind syntax is arrow functions.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first case:

```
this.thing.on(event, someHandler.bind(this))
```

The native [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) is invoked, and it'll work as you expect.

In the second case,

```
this.thing.on(event, someHandler).bind(this)
```

The jQuery `on()` method will return a jQuery object to which the events where bound, and when you call `bind()` on a jQuery object, jquery [`bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) method is being invoked, and it doesn't do what native bind does.

Comment: Awesome. I figured I had a special case where the two just happened to work the same for me. Completely forgot about jquery's bind.